～ずまじ　Is this a double negative?
I was reading a book on Basho's school (蕉門の人々, 1986) and I ran into the following sentence:
仕損ずまじということに捉われるのは下手の心であって...
This is not a quote from Basho or another source from the period. It's an explanation in the author's words of the dictum 名人は危所に遊ぶ. Still,the language is a bit older than what I'm used to, so I'm not sure how to parse 仕損ずまじ.
I'm guessing the ~まじ　termination is the archaic form of ～まい and ～ず　is the old negative auxiliary. Both seem to modify 仕損, which is either しそんずる orしそこなう.
However, I've never seen ～まい and ～ず used in conjunction. I'm not sure if it's possible. And then, I'm not sure what the meaning would be.
So
1-How to parse this construction?
2- How to interpret it?

〜まじ is older form of suffix 〜まい, and in older language, it could be attached to Conclusive (終止形), but 〜ず here is not negative suffix.
You probably heard about -ziru verbs in modern Japanese. Examples:

Continuative (連用形): 信{しん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 信{しん}じる, Attributive (連体形): 信{しん}じる
Continuative (連用形): 損{そん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 損{そん}じる, Attributive (連体形): 損{そん}じる
Continuative (連用形): 仕損{しそん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 仕損{しそん}じる, Attributive (連体形): 仕損{しそん}じる

-zuru verbs are older forms of -ziru verbs. Examples:

Continuative (連用形): 信{しん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 信{しん}ずる, Attributive (連体形): 信{しん}ずる
Continuative (連用形): 損{そん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 損{そん}ずる, Attributive (連体形): 損{そん}ずる
Continuative (連用形): 仕損{しそん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 仕損{しそん}ずる, Attributive (連体形): 仕損{しそん}ずる

Before about 1200 - 1400 (according to Bjarke Frellesvig), some verbs (and adjectives) had distinct forms of Conclusive (終止形) and Attributive (連体形). Attributive (連体形) form took over conclusive function (ending of sentence), and original Conclusive (終止形) form died out. This was completion of process which started many centuries earlier. Sporadic cases of usage of these forms in "opposite" ways (Conclusive (終止形) for attributive function (preceding nouns), Attributive (連体形) for conclusive function (ending of sentence)) are attested already since Old Japanese period (8th century).
For verbs discussed here, -zu was ending of Conclusive (終止形) and -zuru was ending of Attributive (連体形). These endings come from verb su / suru (modern suru "to do"). Examples:

Continuative (連用形): 信{しん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 信{しん}ず, Attributive (連体形): 信{しん}ずる
Continuative (連用形): 損{そん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 損{そん}ず, Attributive (連体形): 損{そん}ずる
Continuative (連用形): 仕損{しそん}じ, Conclusive (終止形): 仕損{しそん}ず, Attributive (連体形): 仕損{しそん}ずる

